# The order of react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to understand how `React hooks` work reading official docs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

And there they say that react relies on the order hooks are called. I still don't get why the order is of importance and why a hook placed in a conditional will cause bugs, could anyone explain?

Particularly this sentence makes me confused:

> React wouldn’t know what to return for the second useState Hook call

why?? Does `react` somehow binds `useState` with `useEffect`?

Then, this question:

> So how does React know which state corresponds to which useState call?

From my understanding there is only one state, so why they are talking about state**s** (plural)?

Comment: its explained here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation

Comment: useEffect is fired each time a dependency changes value, and useState sets a callback that changes a state.
So if you change the value of a state inside a useEffect and that state is a dependency of useEffect then you can find yourself with an infinite loop

Comment: so essentially its a stack. You will receive the items in the order they where placed. If you place things, and one is in an if-statement, when you pop things they will be out of order. Or "shifted" so to speak

Comment: In a nutshell, call order matters simply because that is how React decided to implement hooks. There are many ways hooks could have been implemented (requiring you to provide an additional name/identifier, dependency injection, etc), but they chose to use a call order based implementation because it more elegantly addressed the other issues common to the other implementations. There are a lot of great resources out there that explain the reasoning, but I'll point to this one from Dan Abramov:
https://overreacted.io/why-do-hooks-rely-on-call-order/